# biblatex - Footnote cite custom order

Tags: biblatex, citing, footnotes

I'm writing a thesis and the professor explicitly asked for this specific order in the foot note citations:

{author/s}, {title}, {publisher}, {address}, {year}, {page(if added)}

This book

```
@book{filatov1980,    
  title={La caduta del fascismo},    
  author={Filatov, J.},    
  year={1980},    
  publisher={Teti},
  address={Milano}
}
```

Should output this:

J. Filatov, *La caduta del fascismo*, Teti, Milano, 1980, p.27

I've been searching for a while now and can't find a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are different solutions that you can try:

1. Ask your professor which BibTeX/BibLaTeX style they use themselves and then use that.
2. Try to find an existing style that matches. For example `chem-rsc` for BibLaTeX seems close for books, however for articles the title is not displayed (!) so that may not be ideal.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{filatov1980,    
  title={La caduta del fascismo},    
  author={Filatov, J.},    
  year={1980},    
  publisher={Teti},
  address={Milano},
}
@inbook{filatovpages,    
  booktitle={La caduta del fascismo},    
  author={Filatov, J.},    
  year={1980},    
  publisher={Teti},
  address={Milano},
  pages={27},
}
@article{three,
  title={Three pages about nothing},
  journal={Journal of Nothing},
  author={John Smith},
  year={2010},
  publisher={ABC Publishing},
  address={Sesame Street},
  pages={p. 3}
}

\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[height=8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[style=chem-rsc]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
No policital system lasts forever \footfullcite{filatov1980}. You don't need to read the whole book \footfullcite{filatovpages}. Or read nothing \footfullcite{three}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

3. Modify or create your own BibTeX or BibLaTeX style. Note that for BibLaTeX it is easy to change the appearance of individual fields, but it is harder to change the presence or order of the fields. See for example [How can I create a custom style in biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636561/how-can-i-create-a-custom-style-in-biblatex) for a possible workflow.
4. Ask your professor if a (slightly) different bibliography style would be ok as well (for example styles with *Lastname, A.* are much more common than *A. Lastname*, so it will be easier to satisfy the other requirements if you can put the last name before the initials).